# MVC3 Pop New Window/View and Send Entered Data Back to Original Open Window/View When Done

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, viewstate

In my view a user searches a dropdown that contains a list of "Prescribers" if the Prescriber
does not exist in the Database, they have a button that pops a window containing an "Add New
Prescriber" View.  How can I gather the primary key field data of the new user entered Prescriber and pass it back/repopulate the dropdown to contain the new Prescriber without reloading the original view and losing information entered in other fields?

```
<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DEA_Number, "Prescriber's DEA #")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("DEA_Number", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DEA_Number)
        </div>

        <div>
        <p>Prescriber Not in System? - Click to Add
        <input type="button" name = "ClickMe" value="Add New Prescriber" onclick= "javascript:window.open('/Prescriber/Create/','Customer Search',height='window.screen.height - 100', width='200',left='window.screen.width - 250' ,top='10',status='no',toobar='no',resizable='yes',scrollbars='yes')"/>
        </p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Why dont you do it using a model popup so you dont leave the page.  Then send the data back in an ajax call and update teh page in javascript.

Comment: @feanz  Not sure I understand what you mean by "model popup."  And I'm not leaving the page (at least not in terms of closing it), its still open behind the newly popped window.

Comment: sorry my bad i ment modal popup.  have a look at this http://fancybox.net/

Answer (score 0):

if i have understood you correctly, what you can do is `on popup close` send an ajax request which inserts the `prescriber` in the DB and return you the id like

```
$.post("/URL/To/Controller",{name:'nameEnteredByUSerHere'},function(data){
$("<option/>",{value:data.value,text:data.text}).appendTo("#IDofYourDropDown");
},'json')
```

and the controller will look like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult InsertPrescriber(string name){
//do some validation
//insert data
return Json(new{value="id of the inserted prescriber",text=name});
}
```